# Qt QSettings try to create ini file but none created why?

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

Im trying to create ini file that will hold me the configuration data, I have singletone class
that setting the `QSettings` object like this :

```
... #DEFINE CONFIG_FILE_NAME "myconfig.ini"

m_pSettings = new QSettings(QDir::currentPath()+"/"+CONFIG_FILE_NAME,QSettings::IniFormat);
```

this is accourding the document, but when i look in my application dir, there is none myconfig.ini file created, what im doing wrong ?

Comment: are you sure that code is being called? are you certain you are looking in the right directory?

Comment: yeah sure it called , i have break point and log prints that shows that thid code called and the directory is there

Comment: Did you try to set any variable, and then destroy `m_pSettings`?

Comment: I ran this code on Qt 4.7.2, same result.  The QSettings object is non-null, could call beginWriteArray on it without seg fault.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe in order to force QSettings file to appear you would need to set at least one value in it and then call [sync()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qsettings.html#sync) method. See if an example below would work for you:

```
QSettings* settings = new QSettings(QDir::currentPath() + "/my_config_file.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
settings->setValue("test", "value");
settings->sync();
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: ...or create the QSettings object on stack and let the dtor do the sync.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think that "/"+CONFIG_FILE_NAME return the expected result. May be the cause of your problem..
Anyway operator +() is present in QString class so QDir::currentPath() + "/my_config_file.ini" must work fine.