# How to draw a route between 2 markers using Google Maps API for Android?

Tags: android

This is my first post and I will attempt to keep this brief. I am a rookie programmer currently working on an assignment for university which I could use some help with.

I am making a simple Android application using the Google Maps API. Up to this point, I have initialised the map with the users current location and the feature of adding two markers to the map, the origin and destination respectively. What I am trying to achieve is when the user has set both markers, I would like to add a route between the two points. However, I have followed a few tutorials on the topic, but don't exactly understand what I'm doing.

Please note, I am aware of the use of Polylines to draw a route between two points. Furthermore, I am aware of the Directions API, I'm attempting to look for a way to do it in which I understand what I'm doing. I'm not a strong Java programmer, but am trying my best. I've tried to read the API documentation several times, and I am at a cross roads due to lack of knowledge, so please do not recommend me to read the documentation.

Any help that people could provide would be excellent. Thank you.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28295534/5529263 ?

Comment: Did you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt QSettings try to create ini file but none created why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529263/qt-qsettings-try-to-create-ini-file-but-none-created-why)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android How to show route between markers on googlemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295199/android-how-to-show-route-between-markers-on-googlemaps)